# running the logo language online, in portuguese

Tags: software, specific-software

Logo is a programming language that has, as main (and probably only) purpose the teaching of geometry and introductory computer science

I am looking for an interpreter for logo that runs online and accepts commands in portuguese.

For reference, here is one in english: https://www.calormen.com/jslogo/

I have looked online and found no such site.

If there does not exist a online interpreter, the next best thing would be one that runs on windows and needs no instalation. (the third best thing, one that runs on windows and needs instalation)

I am aware of only one implementation of logo that allows for commands in portuguese, kturtle, and it seems to require linux

Comment: This does not look like a math education question to me. I wonder if you'd have better luck on another SE site.

Comment: Well, logo is a language that has, as main (and probably only) purpose the teaching of geometry and introductory computer science

Comment: Right. But this seems more on the technology end. I hope you find answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a math educator question

Comment: I think this question is more appropriately asked at [Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) might meet your needs well.  It isn't formally Logo (although there is no formal Logo standard TBH), but it has the same turtle graphics capabilities.  It's a far more visual language where you kind of snap together "lego blocks" to create code.  It's a neat system that avoids syntax errors entirely.  If you're using it to teach programming more than geometry, it also prepares students for 21st century languages more than Logo does, with lots of multimedia support and teaching an event-driven paradigm.  It's a completely web-based side with a large global userbase uploading and sharing their projects.  Taking a quick glance at the language support, they seem to support both Portuguese and Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: This makes me so happy! (I should have thought of this.) @josinalvo, I'll be interested to know whether the Portuguese interface is good.